# two karma jasmine tests are running at the same time conflicting on $window

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, isolation-level

I have two Jasmine describe functions in two separate files being run by Karma.

One describe function creates and tests an angularjs controller. That controller has my provider as a dependency injected into it. In the providers `$get` it adds an `init()` method to `$window`, e.g. `$window.init = function(){}`.

My other Jasmine describe function is for testing the provider. It first asserts that there is no `init()` method on `$window`. Then it creates the provider. However, the test fails: there is already an `init()` method on `$window` before the provider has been created. At first I thought how can this be. But running the test using `ddescribe` (with two d's) it passed. So I found the two describe functions from the two files are conflicting.

Shouldn't the tests run separately, particularly if they are testing `$window`? Is there a way to do this?